# Why the fail Post in FireFox has no body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, post

I wanna send message to a closed server by Post using FireFox. But when I check the Post request in the develop tools, I can not find the form data the fail post request in FireFox. The content-length is 18 but the parameter is empty. But when I use Chrome, I can see the form data of [the fail post request in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdX03.png). Is there any difference?And When I open the server, the successful [post request in firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X43LW.png) does have the form data as parameter.

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/manage-login',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        sucess:function()
}
```

Comment: well how is `data` being set?

Comment: @epascarello it's just a dict, `data = {'id':id, 'pwd':pwd}` (`id` and `pwd` are both string). you can see an example in the second picture.